# How to enable access to a specify url when using friendly URLs?

Tags: php, url, prestashop

I'm using Prestashop and there is an issue with account activation by link. I'm using friendly URLs and after clicks activation link, there is an alert, that the page hasn't been found. Here's my `.htaccess` file in main directory of prestashop

```
<FilesMatch "\.tpl$">
    # Apache 2.2
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/module/activationbymail [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>

    # Apache 2.4
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        Require all denied
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/module/activationbymail [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+/?$ /$1/? [L,R=301]
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Which is the URL of the page not found?

Comment: It is like: `myshop-url/module/activationbymail/activation&link=hash`

Comment: Could you please check if problem is with question mark at `/activation?link=hash`?